# How to implement a Pine Script preprocessor

Tags: parsing, pine-script, lexer

The required steps for implementing a Pine Script preprocessor are documented here:

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v3/appendix/Pine_Script_v2_preprocessor.html

It is an 8 step process, quoting:

> Algorithm of @version=2 Pine Script preprocessor in pseudo-code:
>
> 1. Remove comments.
> 2. Replace \r\n or \r with just \n.
> 3. Add \n to the end of the text if it’s missing.
> 4. Lines that contain only whitespace replace with just empty strings.
> 5. Add |INDENT| tokens. They indicate that statement is in a block of code, such as function body, if or for body. Every tab or four spaces are replaced with token |INDENT|.
> 6. Add |B| and |E| tokens. They indicate line begin and line end. Replace empty lines with |EMPTY| tokens.
> 7. Join lines that represent one splitted statement.
> 8. Add code block tokens (|BEGIN| — beginning of the block, |END| — end of the block, |PE| — possible end of the block).

Now, I find step 7 rather puzzling. We're building a preprocessor here, so we have not lexed/parsed anything yet, so how can we tell what lines represent "one splitted statement"?

As per their example:

> After step 6):

```
"|EMPTY|
|B|study('Preprocessor example')|E|
|B|fun(x, y) =>|E|
|B||INDENT|if close > open |E|
|B||INDENT||INDENT|x + y |E|
|B||INDENT|else |E|
|B||INDENT||INDENT|x - y|E|
|EMPTY|
|EMPTY|
|B|a = sma(close, 10)|E|
|B|b = fun(a, 123)|E|
|B|c = security(tickerid, period, b)|E|
|B|plot(c, title='Out', color=c > c[1] ? lime : red, |E|
|B||INDENT| style=linebr, trackprice=true) |E|
|B|alertcondition(c > 100)|E|
|EMPTY|"
```

> After step 7). Note that line with `plot(c, title=` has been joined with the next line:

```
"|EMPTY|
|B|study('Preprocessor example')|E|
|B|fun(x, y) =>|E|
|B||INDENT|if close > open |E|
|B||INDENT||INDENT|x + y |E|
|B||INDENT|else |E|
|B||INDENT||INDENT|x - y|E|
|EMPTY|
|EMPTY|
|B|a = sma(close, 10)|E|
|B|b = fun(a, 123)|E|
|B|c = security(tickerid, period, b)|E|
|B|plot(c, title='Out', color=c > c[1] ? lime : red, style=linebr, trackprice=true) |E|
|EMPTY|
|B|alertcondition(c > 100)|E|
|EMPTY|"
```

Note that not only the lines are joined, but also the `|B||INDENT|` is removed.

Suggestions, anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v3/language/Lines_wrapping.html), a continuation line starts with at least as many INDENTs (four spaces) as the line being continued, plus at least one space but not a multiple of four.

In other words, after converting groups of four leading spaces to INDENTs, if there are still leading spaces, it's a continuation line. So no tokenisation or parsing is necessary.